# Form inputs - drawback of trimming every input

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Recently I've had some problems with users copying information to a form input, but because of empty spaces at the end of the value, my pattern validations were not working ( not allowing them to submit).

Since realizing that there might be an empty space can be troublesome for users, I've made this :

```
  body.on('focusout','input',function(event){
    var target = event.target;
    target.value = target.value.trim();
})
```

I am wondering, can this have any negative effects or drawbacks, and more importantly, can it bite me in the ass at some point? Also, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Apply the `trim()` on the validation function.

Comment: For example it doesn't work on IE8 (I've encountered this problem just few days ago... and I opted for jquery trim function, `$.trim(target.value)`.

Comment: @CBroe The event is bound to the inputs, so I don't understand your point.

@ prasad I am looking for a more complete solution, not rewriting all validators.

@ Alessandro I am not looking to support IE or Edge, but good point

Comment: Sorry, I misread - I thought you where binding two events (focusout and input) to body, but the second one is a limiting selector of course.